# Configuring NAMESPACE and DESCRIPTION when using a Suggested Package

Tags: r, namespaces, package, rstudio

I have written an R package which uses the `rstudioapi::viewer()` function. Obviously, not everyone uses *RStudio*. I am now running in circles trying to correctly configure the `NAMESPACE` and `DESCRIPTION`.

So as not to force users to install a package which they don't need (and/or would be useless on their system), I tried putting `rstudioapi` in the `Suggests` section and call it conditional on its availability:

```
if(.Platform$GUI == "RStudio") {
  if ("rstudioapi" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) {
    rstudioapi::viewer(outfile_path)
  } else {
    message("To view html content in RStudio, run install.packages('rstudioapi').")
    message("Switching method to 'browser'")
    method <- "browser"
  }
```

But on `R CMD CHECK`, I get:

```
checking dependencies in R code ... WARNING
'::' or ':::' import not declared from: 'rstudioapi'
```

So I go and declare it, adding `importFrom(rstudioapi, viewer)` to my `NAMESPACE`. Results:

```
checking package dependencies ... ERROR
Namespace dependency not required: 'rstudioapi'
```

Returning to the [official docs](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-namespaces), I also tried the following:

```
if (requireNamespace("rstudioapi", quietly = TRUE)) {
    rstudioapi::viewer(outfile_path)
  } else { ...
```

To no avail:

```
checking dependencies in R code ... WARNING
'::' or ':::' import not declared from: 'rstudioapi'
'loadNamespace' or 'requireNamespace' call not declared from: 'rstudioapi'
```

So I'm either getting a warning for not declaring it, or an error for declaring it. Damned if you don't, and even more damned if you do kinda thing. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If `rstudioapi` is being used in any of the code in the `R`  directory, you should add it to `Imports` in your DESCRIPTION file. `Suggests` is appropriate for code run in your examples or vignettes, but are not used in the actual code.

Comment: Not according to the official doc... See section 1.1.3.1 in https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html ... It's to be expected that some code will be relevant on some platforms and not others, so I'm pretty sure there must be a solution...

Comment: Problem solved... see my own answer below.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option that occurred to me is to simply not list `rstudioapi` anywhere in your `DESCRIPTION` file.  RStudio has [tips for using the viewer](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/202133558-Extending-RStudio-with-the-Viewer-Pane) that might be helpful and don't require a dependency on `rstudioapi`.

Their recommendation is to use

```
viewer <- getOption("viewer")
if (!is.null(viewer))
  viewer("http://localhost:8100")
else
  utils::browseURL("http://localhost:8100")
```

This works because, on startup, RStudio creates an option called `viewer` and populates it with a function.  If you are not using RStudio, `getOption("viewer")` will return `NULL` and you can redirect it to use the system's default browser. This is essentially what you've already done, but with no additional dependencies required.

This also has the benefit of being about 1000 times faster than checking against `installed.packages`, but that's still measured in nanoseconds, so probably not a big concern (caveat, I only have 192 packages installed.  It could take longer on a system that has downloaded everything on CRAN).

Comment: That works like a charm. I always get a sense of satisfaction when I see `0 errors | 0 warnings | 0 notes` :D

Answer (score 2):

I figured out why I had those warnings / errors. When I added `rstudioapi` to the `Suggests:` list, I inadvertently created a *second* `Suggests:` list. Only the second one was taken into account (and yeah, the existing one was at the bottom of the DESCRIPTION file, totally I missed it. I'm not erasing this in case it happens to someone else...

Comment: Thanks. That just happened to me :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have a few ideas that might help.

It might be useful to refer to Hadley Wickham's online R packages book: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html. I learned most of what (little) I know about packages from his book.

I think that you can add to your DESCRIPTION file, under the "Suggests" field the package `rstudioapi` with the following code:

```
   devtools::use_package("rstudioapi", "Suggests")
```

I've always used the `Roxygen2` package (and more recently `devtools`) for interacting with the NAMESPACE file, so I don't manually edit NAMESPACE.

Here is what my DESCRIPTION file looks like:

```
    Package: stack3
    Type: Package
    Title: What the Package Does (Title Case)
    Version: 0.1.0
    Author: Who wrote it
    Maintainer: The package maintainer <yourself@somewhere.net>
    Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
               Use four spaces when indenting paragraphs within the Description.
    License: What license is it under?
    Encoding: UTF-8
    LazyData: true
    Suggests:
         rstudioapi
    RoxygenNote: 5.0.1
```

I then ran

```
    devtools::build()
```

to get the stack3_0.1.0.tar.gz file. Note that I named my package `stack3`. In running R CMD CHECK stack3_0.1.0.tar.gz, I see that I get no errors and one warning. The warning is due to the text that by default follows License: in the DESCRIPTION file.

```
    R CMD CHECK stack3_0.1.0.tar.gz
    * using log directory ‘/Users/frederickboehm/Box Sync/stack3.Rcheck’
    * using R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
    * using platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
    * using session charset: UTF-8
    * checking for file ‘stack3/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
    * checking extension type ... Package
    * this is package ‘stack3’ version ‘0.1.0’
    * package encoding: UTF-8
    * checking package namespace information ... OK
    * checking package dependencies ... OK
    * checking if this is a source package ... OK
    * checking if there is a namespace ... OK
    * checking for executable files ... OK
    * checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
    * checking for portable file names ... OK
    * checking for sufficient/correct file permissions ... OK
    * checking whether package ‘stack3’ can be installed ... OK
    * checking installed package size ... OK
    * checking package directory ... OK
    * checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... WARNING
    Non-standard license specification:
      What license is it under?
    Standardizable: FALSE
    * checking top-level files ... OK
    * checking for left-over files ... OK
    * checking index information ... OK
    * checking package subdirectories ... OK
    * checking whether the package can be loaded ... OK
    * checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
    * checking whether the package can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
    * checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
    * checking whether the namespace can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
    * checking loading without being on the library search path ... OK
    * checking examples ... NONE
    * checking PDF version of manual ... OK
    * DONE

    Status: 1 WARNING
    See
      ‘/Users/frederickboehm/Box Sync/stack3.Rcheck/00check.log’ for details.
```

I hope that I understood your question and that this response is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that HW's page explains pretty much what I've tried last based on official docs... In your code (excluding examples / vignettes), did you include conditional execution, something like `if (requireNamespace("pkg", quietly = TRUE)) { pkg::f() }`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question, but I think that you want to replace `pkg` with `rstudioapi` and `f` with `viewer` when you have code in your package that contains the call to `rstudioapi::viewer()`. Does that make sense? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I'm not sure that you need to edit the NAMESPACE file.

Comment: The "pkg" and "f" are just placeholders for any package and function, so yes to your first question. What I meant is that it might work fine to just add the package name to the Sugests list, if you don't actually use it in your code... So I was curious to know if you did use any suggested package's functions in your own package's functions or not.

Comment: For the NAMESPACE file, I don't know of any tool that will generate a fully functional one by itself, unless the package is really really simple. Roxygen can generate the exports for instance, but that's about it AFAIK!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I did create a package and use the conditional in my function. I haven't tested it on a computer that doesn't have the rstudioapi package installed, however.

Comment: Ok thx good to know... I'll see if I can get any further fiddling with `devtools` a bit...